# Poisson ideals vs. ideals generated by Poisson central elements

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

Let $R$ be a Poisson algebra (over $\mathbb C$, say) with Poisson center $Z = \{c \in R : \{c,R\} = 0\}$ and consider two types of ideals $I \leq R$:

1. $I = \langle (c_i) \rangle$ is generated by Casimirs $c_i$, i.e. each  $c_i\in Z$
2. $I$ is a Poisson ideal, i.e. $\{I,R\} \leq I$.

I'm having trouble distinguishing these geometrically: both seem to be about subschemes of $Spec\ R$ that are unions of symplectic leaves. But that seems too good to be true (or I would hope someone would have told me already). Still, I will ask:

> If $I$ is a Poisson ideal, is $\sqrt{I} = \sqrt{ \langle I \cap Z \rangle}?$

If so, what is a reference? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Nicola's answer below certainly gives the desired counterexample.  I just wanted to mention that if $I$ is already radical then there is a simple obstruction to equality of $I$ and $\langle I\cap Z \rangle$.  Namely, the Poisson bracket descends to a Lie algebra structure on $I/I^2$ (the "co-normal Lie algebra").  If $I$ is generated by elements of $Z$ then this Lie bracket will be abelian, but most conormal algebras are not.  For example, for the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ defining the origin in the dual of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, we have $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2\cong\mathfrak{g}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not that familiar with the algebraic approach but the intersection on the rhs seems quite hard to me. Take the Poisson structure on the plane given by $\{x,y\}=xy$. Then $Z$ contains only constant functions and therefore for any Poisson ideal $I$ you have $I\cap Z$ equal to $Z$ or $0$ depending whether the ideal contains constants or not. Take $I=\langle x,y\rangle$ and it looks to me your condition is not fulfilled...

To put it another way there seems to me to be many situations in which the Poisson center is given only by constants and still the symplectic foliation is quite rich, thus many Poisson ideals.

Comment: Being a Poisson ideal, $I$ is also a associative ideal. So to make things interesting, it should not contain the constants. I think your example completely settles the question (in the negative).

Comment: To put it another way: being a symplectic leaf is still quite far from being a level set of Casimir functions. There are many examples of algebraic Poisson manifolds with dense leaves, or leaves which are dense inside closed submanifolds.

Comment: Okay, so the group-action analogue is that a $G$-invariant subvariety may fail to be the intersection of a number of $G$-invariant hypersurfaces.

Comment: Maybe more than an analogue; what is around here is the infinitesimal action of all the Hamiltonian vector fields...

Comment: You also asked for references, I guess that here http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/paper_file/glasgow/Gordon/poisord.pdf you may find some pieces fo the general theory...

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli: I apologize for the intrusion, but do $x$ and $y$ represent the coordinate functions on $\mathbb R^2$? If so, your Poisson bracket is not antisymmetric, so I'm obviously misinterpreting your notations.

Comment: @Alex M. Yes they are the coordinate functions and no I do not see any problem with antisymmetry. It is the Poisson bracket given by the (evidently) antisymmetric bivector $\pi=xy\partial_x\wedge\partial_y$. Is this clearer?

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli: Yes, this explicit notation makes things clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the following references can be of help.

- MR1764436 (2001d:53093) Reviewed 
  Grabowski, Janusz(PL-WASW-IM)
  Isomorphisms of Poisson and Jacobi brackets. (English summary) Poisson geometry (Warsaw, 1998), 79–85, 
  Banach Center Publ., 51, Polish Acad. Sci., Warsaw, 2000.
- MR2027202 (2004k:17042) Reviewed 
  Grabowski, J.(PL-PAN); Poncin, N.(LUX-CUL-DM)
  Automorphisms of quantum and classical Poisson algebras. (English summary) 
  Compos. Math. 140 (2004), no. 2, 511–527.